# MongoDB BSON document too large error on Flask app but runs fine when executed standalone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm struggling with a "bson document too large error" from a simple mongo query. The query is executed in a small python script - part of a larger Flask app - stored on an AWS EC2 instance. What's odd is that the query and script execute fine when I execute the script as a function outside of the flask app.
The query, posted below, is very precise and the collection it targets is also small - in fact, I created a test collection with just one document, and again it raised the bson error.

```
def lookupAV(collection, bbl):
    result=collection.aggregate([{'$match':{'_id': bbl}},{'$project':{'AV': 1,'_id': 0}}])
    gh = list(result)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gh[0]['AV'],orient='columns')
    print('dataframe shape is ' + str(df.shape))
    return(df)
```